# How to create a CSS rule that will only apply when the body/html direction is "rtl"?

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

We have an English website, like this https://www.example.com And now we are using GTranslate service which will generate an Arabic version of the website, like this https://www.example.com/ar/

After checking the Arabic version, we find GTranslate put the following attributes to the html tag, as below:

[image]

But that is not enough. I check https://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support#Method_2:_rtl.css and there are many rules to be changed to support rtl languages.

But we cannot replace the current style.css of the WP site since we still need the English version as well.

So, I plan to add some special rules for rtl languages.

It is possible to use a language specific rule, such as:

```
p:lang(ar) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

However, since there are a [dozen of rtl languages](https://www.andiamo.co.uk/resources/right-to-left-languages/), I want to create a rule that only apply when the html "dir" attribute is "rtl". Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
html[dir="rtl"]
```

Comment: In https://www.w3schools.in/css3/css-dir-pseudo-class, it said "The main problem with using Dir Pseudo-Class is that very few browsers support it, and out of all the latest web browsers, only Firefox supports it.", so finally I choose attribute selector which is compatible in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Directionality Pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#dir-pseudo): `:dir(rtl)`

Comment: +1, but note that while it might be what the OP needs, it is not what the question asks (a rule that only apply when the html "dir" attribute is "rtl").

Comment: @Amadan - Yes, fair point.